# NgXs: TypeError: Class constructor MyState cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: angular, ngxs

I'm integrating [NgXs](https://www.ngxs.io/) Store into my app. I've created few simple states and trying to select data from them, but when app is launched I get the runtime error:

```
TypeError: Class constructor MyState cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at ngxs-store.js:2166
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at selectFromAppState (ngxs-store.js:2162)
    at Store.selectSnapshot (ngxs-store.js:2343)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured out that I forgot to supply the state class to `NgxsModule`.

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        NgxsModule.forRoot([
            ...
            MyState // this line was missing, so the store cannot instantiate the state
        ], {
            developmentMode: !environment.production
        })
    ],
    exports: [
        NgxsModule
    ]
})
export class StoreModule {}
```